# Laravel - Fetching 1m+ rows and passing to vueJS

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I've never had to fetch so much data before so I'm unsure how to go about this.

What I'm trying to do is fetch 1m+ records from a single table and display it using a vueJS front-end.

Obviously the table will be paginated but a search-box needs to be able to search through the table super quick.

I've looked into chunking but I'm not sure how to integrate this.

The following doesn't appear to be working...

The code that's commented out is taking 13 seconds when accessing the API direct and that's just 5000 rows.

```
public function getTransactionsV2() {

    // $transactions = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM transactionsV2 LIMIT 5000"));
    / $transactions = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('transactionsV2')->limit(5000)->get();

    DB::connection('mysql2')->table('transactionsV2')->orderBy('id')->limit(1000)->chunk(100, function ($transactions) {
        foreach ($transactions as $transactions) {
            return $transaction;
        }
    });

    // return $transactions;
}
```

Comment: 1m+ rows? Wow! It will probably crash the browser

Comment: Not sure what you're doing in your `->chunk()` function; that loop is probably an issue (looping all 1000 records for every chunk?). That being said, something like `->limit(1000)->get()->chunk(100)`, without the closure, should return 10 arrays of 100 records, or even `->paginate(100)`. Perhaps read up on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion, there's a chunking method for DB results and Collections; the one you have is DB chunking, which takes that secondary function, while the one I'm describing is when you already have a collection. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-chunk vs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#chunking-results

Comment: I'm not familiar with chunking @TimLewis. Is that not the correct way to use it?

Comment: What would you recommend then @AlonEitan. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Dally I never had to deal with such huge amount of data, but for text based searches I would use a [full-text search index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) (Not sure how it will perform with 1m rows though)